# What does the character "%XX" mean in C language?

Tags: c

I'm having trouble finding what does %XX mean in C

an example would be like: `printf("%XX\n", num);`

edit: num is an int

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html

Comment: `man printf` is short version for the above.

Answer (score 1):

print `num` converted to `unsigned int` as a hexadecimal number and then print char 'X'

Answer (score 1):

In a `printf` format string, `%XX` is `%X` followed by `X`.

The `%X` says to format an `unsigned int` argument as hexadecimal, using uppercase (ABCDEF for the “digits”).

The `X` is simply a literal X that says to print an “X” after the hexadecimal numeral.